# Which JS frameworks are being used in iCloud.com?

Tags: javascript, icloud

By looking at the scripts being loaded in [iCloud.com](http://www.icloud.com), I was only able to recognize **jQuery**.

However, I couldn't tell if the JS code in other files is **custom** or belongs to some other **framework**. For educational purposes only, can anybody give me some more information?

Comment: run all the code through http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: I'm not sure why this is closed as 'localized', it's a good question in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see they are using :

- Sizzle CSS Selector Engine
- jQuery JavaScript Library v1.6.2
- Raphael 1.5.2 - JavaScript Vector Library

Plus some custom written JS stuff

Comment: [This is their custom JS stuff](http://jsbin.com/eqorug/edit#javascript,html)